# Using a data table in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to create a data table in Microsoft Excel. From the data table, I have to derive the returns that is based on the changing first year sales[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiAsc.jpg). The 11%, 12% and 13% are the different discount rates. I am not able to get the appropriate percentages of returns for the values since I am unsure what my column input value and row input value should be. Attached is what I have got in my Excel file so far.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To help you better, could you please describe how you need to use these discount rates?